# PHPExcel wrongfully throwing a #DIV/0

Tags: tabs, phpexcel

I have an excel sheet with multiple tabs. The first tab is a summary of information found in the other tabs. I need to read that tab.

First I had a lot of problems with the calculations, but apparently there's a bug in the new version and now I am using  `getOldCalculatedValues()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114964/phpexcel-excel-read-is-not-working-for-some-cells-with-calculation#comment38502751_24114964).

Now it's much better, but I still have two values not getting through, and instead throwing a `#DIV/0!`

This is my code: http://codepad.org/JWNhwyG5

Summary tab (red lines are the ones):

1. Total personnel costs in % is '`=Expenditure!C36`'
2. Of which fixed/structural costs in % is '`=Expenditure!D36`'

Summary tab:

[image]

This is the tab 'Expenditure'.

[image]

This is C117:

[image]

Comment: What is `C117`? Are there any other *incell* calculations? Try looking at every cell included in the calculation. Try doing it by hand to see what it should do.

Comment: Hi, I have added the C117. It's a sum. I checked everything, and excel is right. I think PHPExcel has a different order of doing the calculation. If they try to divide before the sum is executed, it's normal they think it's 0. But how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how PHP handles this, and I find it stupid if it would try to place "placeholder values".. If it is a PHP problem I'm out. Good luck!

Comment: PHPExcel calculates dynamically when you request a calculated value for a cell, calculating any additional values that are required by cells used in formulae. In the case of `toArray()`, individual cells are process by column within each row in turn, although any cell that contains a formula that references other cells will calculate those other cells as well. There is a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/MarkBaker/5908357) that shows how to enable debugging for formulae, allowing you to see what calculations are executed and the results at all stages of the process.

Comment: You mention a `bug` in the new version: can you be more explicit. If there's a known bug, then a reference to it would be useful

Comment: If you are using `getOldCalculatedValue()` (toArray() doesn't do this, and your code doesn't show you doing this) then PHPExcel doesn't do any calculations, but simply reads the result from the last time the cell was calculated by MS Excel itself. If you get a `#DIV/0` then, that is what was read as the claculated result from MS Excel itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that your code shows you are applying a read filter, so that only cells `A3:D60` are loaded into PHPExcel. Any formula that references a cell outside of that range, such as `C117` will not be able to retrieve the value of that cell to use in the calculation, so it will be treated as an empty cell.

```
C36 = C35 / C117
=> 15770000 / NULL
=> #DIV/0
```

I'd suggest that you don't apply the read filter, but load the whole spreadsheet into PHPExcel, or at least extend the range of your read filter so that it does include all relevant cells and all relevant worksheets, so that you have cell C117 available for use in your calculation.

There would be no need for you to use `getOldCalculatedValue()` then either

```
$arrFatalError = array();

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");

$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("/excel/myfile.xlsx");

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName("summary")
    ->rangeToArray('A3:D60', null,true,true,true);
```

Comment: I obviously was doing the wrong things. I thought the reading filter was meant to filter what I wanted to read, and interpreted the post I referred to as PHPExcel have a problem with the calculation engine. Thanks for your help!